# How to let backend file (app.js) process any url comes from the frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express app contains two files on the root

(index.js + index.html)

and a folder named: server, contains a file [app.js] that listening to port 3000

I run index.html through Live Server on port: 5500

In [index.html + index.js] I fetch data through buttons from port 3000 where app.js is listening on, and it working good.

But my problem is when the user type a link in the frontend (localhost:5500/NotFound), in this case the browser won’t find the link and will get an error: Cannot Get…

What I want is to show a message “Not Found” for any invalid URL comes from the frontend

my question **isn’t about 404 error itself** but how to let the frontend handles the navigation in the backend.

my app structure is like this:

[image: send 404 to frontend]

```js
//app.js on port:3000/backend
app.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send('This is a test'))

app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.send('Not Found'))
//OR
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, '/404.html');
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`server up`))
```

```js
//index.js on port 5500/frontend
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   fetch('http://localhost:3000/test)
   .then(...)
})
```

now let’s say that it’s in the localhost:

frontend (index.html + index.js) are on http://127.0.0.1:5500/

backend (app.js) is on http://127.0.0.1:3000/

this working good if it requested from backend http://127.0.0.1:3000/ but if the request handled from the frontend (http://127.0.0.1:5500/NoExists ) it gets [**Cannot GET /NoExists**]

So, how to send a message {Not Found} to http://127.0.0.1:5500/NoExists?

in other words:
let app.js (backend) triggered by any request sent from index.js(frontend)

Comment: But `app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.send('Not Found'))` should do the job, no ? I have the same code with you and it worked.

Comment: as I said, it works when a request handled from localhost:3000 (backend), but if the request came from localhost:5000 (frontend) it get an error: Cannot Get…
is it working with you with the same structure as mine?

Comment: I set up only a backend part, but when I visit a non-defined route on the browser it worked (I have the 404 page). Oh now I understand your problem. You want to "forward" http://127.0.0.1:5500/NoExists  to http://127.0.0.1:3000/NoExists and then have 404 page ? In this case, I don't know how to help you ...

Comment: Thanks Dang, yes that what I want

Answer (score 0):

Use the `response.status` method

```js
app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.status(404).send('Not Found'))
```

Edit: hopefully I understand the question now

You can leave the path blank to let it work for any undefined routes

```js
app.get((req, res) => res.status(404).send('Not Found'));
// OR
app.get((req, res) => res.status(404).sendFile(__dirname, '/404.html'));
```

Edit 2: So from the video you sent, I think you want to display a 404 message in the front end.

Create a file in the same location as `index.html` and name it `404.html`. This is just a normal html file, but its contents will be displayed when a page isn't found.

It looks like you're using live server, and I've found that the 404.html file doesn't work on live server, but it will work for most hosting services. Check [this article](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/quicktips/not-found/) or [this one](https://www.htmldog.com/techniques/404/).

Comment: thank you for your advice, I wrote in **bold** that: 404 isn't my issue

Comment: But you asked “how to send a message {Not Found} to http://127.0.0.1:5500/NoExists?”?

Comment: yes, you alright, may the title wasn’t describing the problem, for this I changed it. However thank you for your reply

Comment: Oh, I think I know what you mean now. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Ok, I think I get it this time. I'll edit my answer again.

Comment: many thanks Luke for the provided links .htaccess on hosting will solve it,  I appreciate your time